React Axios Error: How to Fix 'fetchProducts' Undefined Issue
I am new to react try to develop a prototype
I tried with different axios packages but still I am getting the below error
can you let me know how to fix it
providing my code and sandbox below
I googled but still no luck
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jg3f1a?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FProductListing.jsx,src%2FApp.css,src%2FApp.js,public%2Findex.html
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'
      );
      setProducts(response.data);
      setFilteredProducts(response.data); // Initialize filtered products
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    }
  };
  fetchProducts();
}, []); // Calculate indices for slicing the array


"still I am getting the below error" - What error?

You ought to add that this is specifically in stackblitz as well.  The error you're encountering is not a generic programming error: it's specifc to that tool.

Drop your axios version to: 0.16.2 via the package.json file, save the project, then reload.
Here is a forked version of your project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qj6mx6?file=package.json
This is a known issue with stackblitz which they have not remedied yet:
https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/2722
